# How to pass data between InfoPath forms in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, infopath, form

I just watch this video [Pass data between InfoPath forms in SharePoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nGl-Se2cOQ)  but I do not know how to do like that. I use Infopath designer 2013. Anyone can help me. Thank in advance

Comment: Asp. Net state service and code behind infopath forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you're looking for is at this link:
[Passing Data into a Form: Input Parameters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/02/26/passing-data-into-a-form-input-parameters/)

It would be no different for InfoPath 2013 than for InfoPath 2010.  That said, you're going to need to know how to write code behind for your InfoPath form and then have access, or know someone who has access, to central administration to publish your form.

The basic idea is to build a link in the first form (by using a function to build the url with data in the form) to the second form.  The second form would then have the code behind that would read the parameters you passed it on form load.